# Select distinct int from 2 possible fields in list using linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, visual-studio

I've looked for a solution but I can't quite figure it. It strikes me that linq should be able to handle this neatly but I'm not the best at formulating linq queries. Basically I have a class;

```
public class Message
{
    public int CreatedByPersonID { get; set; }
    public int? PostedToPersonID { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm looking for is the linq equivilant of;

```
List<int> personIDs = new List<int>();
foreach (Message message in messages)
{
    if (!personIDs.Contains(message.CreatedByPersonID))
    {
        personIDs.Add(message.CreatedByPersonID);
    }
    if (message.PostedToPersonID != null && !personIDs.Contains(message.PostedToPersonID.Value))
    {
        personIDs.Add(message.PostedToPersonID.Value);
    }
}
```

*Is* there a linq version of this? Or am I expecting too much of the technology...? I know I'm looking for some version of `Select()` but I don't know how to formulate a `distinct` with multiple fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<int> personIDs = 
     messages.SelectMany(m => m.PostedToPersonID.HasValue ?
                  new int[] { m.PostedToPersonID.Value, m.CreatedByPersonID } :
                  new int[] { m.CreatedByPersonID })
             .Distinct()
             .ToList();
```

Another option is enumerating twice:

```
List<int> personIDs =
    messages.Where(m => m.PostedToPersonID.HasValue)
            .Select(m => m.PostedToPersonID.Value)
            .Concat(messages.Select(m => m.CreatedByPersonID))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

But possibly without Linq you have more readable and faster code

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetAllPersonIdsFrom(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
{
     foreach(var message in messages)
     {
         yield return message.CreatedByPersonID;

         if (message.PostedToPersonID.HasValue)
             yield return message.PostedToPersonID.Value;
     }
}
```

---

One more solution - single enumerating with distinct values

```
public static List<int> GetDistinctPersonIdsFrom(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
{
    HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>();

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        ids.Add(message.CreatedByPersonID);
        if (message.PostedToPersonID.HasValue)
            ids.Add(message.PostedToPersonID.Value);
    }

    return ids.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Works :-) (can't accept yet but I will). I'm inclined towards the first option. A little ugly but the initial `SelectMany` iterates through the list once rather than twice with `Contact()`

Comment: @DiskJunky one iteration, yes, but lots of arrays creation. Actually, I'd measured performance first, or even go without Linq :)

Comment: I can't help thinking that `Distinct()` iterates through the list a second time though. Is there a "single pass" solution to this?

Comment: @DiskJunky well, you are right, collection will be enumerated twice - when Distinct called, and when ToList called. If enumerable is not good for you (avoid calling ToList), then you can't avoid enumerating sequence twice

Comment: fair enough on the iterations. Can you explain the `yield` solution though? I've read up on it but I'm struggling to understand how it works. Wouldn't `yield return message.CreatedByPersonID` return back such that the `if` is never hit?

Comment: @DiskJunky nope, with `yield return` values returned one by one, and execution continues right after `yield` statement.

Comment: Note that IMHO the OP code is possibly as or more performant than any of these, once you include the `.Distinct` needed for the `yield` version, with the last one the most likely to be both as or more readable and as or more performant. Definitely choose readable code and profile the result.

Comment: @MarkHurd nope, original code used one or two List.Contains search for each item. Distinct is faster, because it uses Set to determine unique elements